# Filebeat multiline codec not working in my case

Tags: multiline, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have defined multiline codec in filebeat.yml like below

```
multiline.pattern: '^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} '
 multiline.negate: true
 multiline.match: after
```

But it does not seem to be working as multiple lines of log get appended together like below

Single line of log

```
2017-05-07 22:29:43 [0] [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.app.task.ChannelActiveCheckTask - ---- 
Inside checkIfChannelActive execution ----
```

The corresponding log stored in elastic search after multi-line parsing

```
   ---- Inside checkIfChannelActive execution ---- 2017-05-09 08:16:13 [0] [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  
    XYZZ - XYZ :: XYZ 2017-05-09 08:16:13 [0] [pool-2-thread-1] INFO XYZ - XYZYZZ
```

Since the above did not work, I also tried using the below multi-pattern but it does not work too

```
multiline.pattern: '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}'
```

Below is my logstash.conf

```
input {
beats {
port => 5044
}
}

filter {
mutate {
gsub => ["message", "\n", " "]
}
grok {
match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} [%{NOTSPACE:uid}] [%
{NOTSPACE:thread}] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{DATA:class}-%{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]
overwrite => [ "message" ]
}
date {
match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
target => "@timestamp"
}
if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
drop { }
}
}

output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => localhost
index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}
}
```

Can someone help me fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

filebeats does not recognize grok patterns. You have to use the regex.

You can find the definitions of the patterns @ https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns